# .Net Core 5 - Identity User Association?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Brand new to .Net Core, so sorry for basic question.

I am trying to create a User that has Shops. So far, i have these models defined:

```
public class Shop
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then i subclass the default Identity User to add the asosciation as well:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
}
```

I run my migrations and the database seems to be setup correctly, with a FK defined in shops for a userID.

So far, so good.

BUT - i now want to test it, but have no idea how i get the user out as an object, so i can make the association?

I tried:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestShopAsync()
    {
        // Associate shop with user
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        // Create a new shop
        Shop newShop = new Shop();
        newShop.Name = "Min Butik";
        newShop.User = (ApplicationUser)user;
        

        // Save user and shop?
        _db.Shops.Add(newShop);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return View();
    }
```

But when i try to access that action in the URL, it says it doesn't exist - i suspect it has something to do with it being "async" but i couldn't find a way to get the user that is logged in, in a way that wasn't async.

Am i missing something? I feel like i am really close, but i stubmled at the finish line and can't get back up.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Please be specific and ask independent questions independently.

Comment: I am specific? TLDR; How do i get the identity user out as an object in a non-async way..?

Comment: No you're not being specific. Not being able to find the url is separate from whether an endpoint is synchronous or not and further is separate from using a derived type of identity user

Comment: `async` code is good if you can use it, don't try to avoid it. Here it's perfectly usable because the root call is from a controller action which supports `async`. Why do you want to avoid `async`? what's wrong with your code? is there any exception or unwanted result?

Comment: Could you send the URL you're trying to hit and the controller class name with all annotations on it as well as all annotations on your TestShopAsync method? I think that you are trying to use the wrong URL, the EF Core code you showed is not probably related in any way to your problem.